# tf.keras.backend way of replacing a tensors value if it's less than 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

I am using Keras with the Tensorflow backend.

In my loss function I have a tensor where I need to replace the elements that are less than 1 with a 1.

I can see loads of functions available to me in the docs
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend

but I'm not sure how to go about this.

If I do:

```
a_ = tf.Print(
    message='a_shape',
    input_=a_,
    data=[tf.shape(a_)]
)
```

I get the shape as:

```
y_shape[128]
```

I need to essentially iterate through this tensor replacing elements that are less than 1 with a 1.

How would I do this using the keras tensorflow API?

Thanks -

Answer (score 1):

if `a` is your tensor you can do the following:

`b = a*tf.cast(a>1, 'float32') + tf.cast(a<=1, 'float32')`

Answer (score 1):

A "keras" answer suitable to all backends:

```
isGreater = K.cast(K.greater(a_,1),K.floatx())
result = (a_*isGreater) + (1 - isGreater)
```